# Linear Models Hat matrix

Tags: least-squares, matrix, projection

For OLS in matrix form, we are taught that Hat matrix is $X(X^TX)^-X^T$, and is idempotent etc, i.e. when it multiplies with itself, it will self cancel and thus lead back to the same Hat matrix.

I was wondering why can't the inverse in the middle just unravel itself, thus causing two self cancellations (due to X multiplying with its inverse, likewise for $X^T$), but this self-implosion can only occur when we mutliply the Hat onto something else (like when we multiply it with itself, for e.g.)

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by the "inverse" of a non-square matrix $X$?

Comment: Ah... I see now. Thank you so much, clearly need to brush up my linear algebra...

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the inverse is a distributive operation, thus in principle it could be applied separately to terms in a product.

However, as [whuber mentioned in comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/500247/linear-models-hat-matrix#comment925298_500247), the *actual* inverse operation is not defined for non-square matrices.